# How to determine the correct web.config file

Tags: c#, web-config, backend

Currently we have multiple web.config files in the backend server.

Is that possible to know which one is being used by the backend code?

Comment: Nope, only one web.config is used, the one that is located in root folder of your site. Other webconfigs, if any, are only auxiliary and can overwrite some elements for the scope of the folder they are located.

Comment: Yes only one is used, but how to identify that one? I have one in my site root directory and few more in my site api directory. I need to make changes to the api web config but I am not sure which is the correct config file.

Comment: Is the "site api directory" a separate website? Or just a subfolder in the only website?

Comment: It is a subfolder.

Comment: And is the subfolder marked as an "application" or it's just a subfolder? You are not very talkative and I am about to give up asking.

Comment: It is a subfolder but I also see it in IIS as a different site, if that’s what you are asking. Sorry I am still learning this subject, my knowledge is not great.

Comment: This should [shed some light on the issue](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides).